# Why can't I place my NSDictionary data into a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am have an NSDictionary which multiple dictionaries like this:

```
{
        complete = 0;
        description = Description;
        "due_date" = "2014-02-28 16:30:03";
        name = Task;
        priority = 2;
        "task_id" = 1;
        "user_id" = 1;
    },
        {
        complete = 0;
        description = "";
        "due_date" = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
        name = "";
        priority = 0;
        "task_id" = 2;
        "user_id" = 1;
    }
```

I would like to display each instance of "name" in my UITableView

I have tried this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    for (task in tasks) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[task objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

But the app crashes each time I attempt to do run it.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the error I get:

> Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]

Comment: please enable exceptional breakpoints and tell which line causes an error (and what error is)

Comment: Do you have an array (`tasks`) with multiple dictionaries in it? Why do you have a `for` loop?

Comment: I do have tasks with multiple dictionary. The for loop divides each dictionary, I thought in the loop I could add code that will add the name to the table?

Comment: As well as what everyone else has mentioned, your app will crash because you are returning `nil` from `cellForRow...`

Comment: I changed it from nill, to UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath]; and it works now :)

Comment: Did any of the answers help you?

Comment: @PeterStuart : any update? would you mind replying emails?

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to look like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    cell.textLabel.text = [[tasks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];

    return cell;
}
```

The problem was that `task` was a dictionary, so it didn't respond to `objectAtIndex:`.

BTW, you need to create or dequeue a `UITableViewCell` instance as well, but I simply corrected your crashing issue for you.

Comment: That too. I was just correcting the part of his code that was causing a crash. :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting a crash is because you are returning `nil` from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

I think you are also misunderstanding how this table view data source method works. It gets called once per table cell in your table (hence why you return a `UITableViewCell` from it...). You don't need to be looping over your data collection inside it - you should be getting the correct data object from your collection based on the indexPath.

On top of that, as others have said, if `tasks` is in fact an `NSDictionary`, then it won't respond to `objectAtIndex`. In all likelihood, you probably want your data collection to be an `NSArray`, if it isn't already.

Edit:

Judging by the error you are getting, `tasks` is in fact an `NSArray` (as the error is caused by returning `nil` from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`). Try the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *task = [tasks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [task objectForKey:@"name"];
    return cell;
}
```

Edit 2:

Also, you should be using `objectForKey:` instead of `valueForKey:`.

Answer (score 0):

#### **Dictionaries don't have indices.**

You can't call a `objectAtIndex:` method on a dictionary, that's why your app is crashing. Instead, you need to use `objectForKey:` with the appropriate key to get the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing those NSDictionary's in an NSArray.  An NSArray will allow you to hold them, along with accessing objects with "objectAtIndex".

If you need to add NSDictionary's at run-time, try using an NSMutableArray, which allows you to add and remove array objects when needed.